# Is "if ... else if ... else ..." any different from "if ... else { if ... else ...}" semantically?

Tags: c, if-statement, language-lawyer

I believe all of you, when learning C, have learned this syntax:

```
if (condition 1) {
    statements
} else if (condition 2) {
    statements
} ...
else {
    statements
}
```

But after reading [N1570, § 6.8.4.1 *The `if` statement*](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.8.4.1), I find absolutely nothing talking about the chained `else if` statements, unlike other languages that provide keywords like `ElseIf` or `elif` for this purpose.

According to my understanding, the whole `if(...){...}else{...}` is one single statement (the `else` clause may not be existent, which is irrelevant). So when it comes to parsing, as shown in below codes,

```
if (condition) {}
else
    one_statement;
```

```
if (condition) {}
else
    if (something else) {} else {}
```

The indented `if` statement in the second block is equivalent to the indented `one_statement;` in the first block, in terms of "a syntactic 'statement' unit".

Then, as C allows flexible spacing, any combination of an aggregate positive number of spaces, tabs and newlines are equivalent. So after re-spacing the above code, it turns into

```
if (condition) {
} else if (something else) {
} else {
}
```

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct.

Comment: I could swear there is dupe of this, but I can not find it.

Comment: american science

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I find absolutely nothing talking about the chained else if statements

That's because there is nothing special about chaining `if` statements specifically, as opposed to chaining, say, an `if` and a loop. Whatever is chained to the end of the `else` clause becomes part of that `else` clause in its entirety:

```
if (x)
    ...
else if (y)
         ...
     else if (z)
             ...
          else
             ...
```

Above, `if (y)` belongs to the `else` branch of `if (x)`, along with the entire chain of statements in its branch. Whitespace does not matter, so the chain can be re-formatted the way you show at the bottom of your question.

**Note:** C does have to deal with a special case of [*dangling else*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else), but it happens when `if`s are nested, not when they are chained.